# SagePay Direct Integration Kit v4.00

Tags: .net, opayo

Is there a Dot Net SagePay Direct Integration kit for version 4.00?

I've tried to find it on the SagePay website but can't find it or any mention of one.

Comment: @Cid Last update of that was 2015!

Comment: This is probably also too old, but may be worth a look. SagePay supplied me with their integration kit source code some time ago and I ended up fixing a couple of bugs and throwing it up on Github. Feel free to give it a try. https://github.com/WiredUK/SagePay.IntegrationKit

Comment: Having said that, asking for software recommendations is off topic here I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. That source code on GitHub could well be useful. Does Sage ever answer questions?

Comment: Their support is usually pretty good in my experience, if they weren't I'm only a few minutes drive from there to go knock on the door :)

Answer (score 1):

A quick update. Phoned sage today (17th July). They said that they are hoping to upgrade the testing server to support 4.00 at the end of the week.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, not currently.

I've custom-coded. As of now, v4.00 is not supported on the testing server, despite supposedly going live today.

Comment: many thanks, that's really useful to know. Any news on when the v4.00 test servers will be 'live'?

Comment: I don't work there, but I called today (as I'm ready to test) and they said it would be a good few more days and we would receive an email when it was ready.

Comment: Reply from SagePay support (received 2019/07/05) - 'We are planning to have protocol 4.00 go live in test this Monday 8th July.'

Comment: Sill awaiting an answer from SagePay Support.

Comment: Yeah, it's not live yet. I've got a test version of VPS Direct v4.0 written and it's still returning "The detailed error is: 3097 : The VPSProtocol value is outside the valid range. Should be between 2.00 and 3.00." They must have problems with it.

Comment: A maintenance notification was sent on 15/07 for planned maintenance to the test server on 16/07 @ 7AM to enable the roll out of 3DS V2 compliance changes.

Whether this was just prep work and not the actual upgrade or they've just missed the deadline I don't know

Comment: Just to update, the test portal seems to be working now, I've got a succesful test auth from a VPS 4.00 call this morning.

Comment: I'm getting a response with v4, however the 3DSv2 (triggered by CHALLENGE as the card holder name) is timing out.

Answer (score 0):

Details of the 4.0 protocol's draft are [available for download](https://www.sagepay.co.uk/library/document/directintegrationandprotocol4guidelinespdf).

Howvever, as mentioned above the test gateway doesn't correctly respond to it.  If you send a 4.0 request you'll get back.

`3097 : The VPSProtocol value is outside the valid range. Should be between 2.00 and 3.00.`

I've asked Sagepay to clarify when it will be available.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like v4.00 is now working on the SagePay test server. Just tried it and got an error INVALID 3228 : The ThreeDSNotificationURL field format is invalid.
As I haven't implemented that field yet it seems to me that v4.00 is now for use on the test server.